# Trying to only calculate a certain cell if another cell says "paid"

Tags: google-sheets

Does anyone know how to calculate a total of say cell (i11:i40) but only if a cell in that same row says paid? Basically i have all of my jobs for my company in google sheets and the total profit is adding up and giving me a total in cell i10. I only want that total in i10 to be the total of all the jobs paid and not to include the unpaid. So i need to subtract that unpaid amount if a certain cell says unpaid. Thanks and sorry if this doesn't make sense lol

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your range that may hold a value of "paid" is J11:J40.

In I10, use this formula:

`=SUMIF(J11:J40,"paid",I11:I40)`

Of course, you'll need to replace `J11:J40` with the actual range from your sheet that may hold a value of "paid."